# I want my Opencv to use threading to increase fps

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, frame-rate

My opencv code is lagging in raspbpi but in pc its smooth. Can anyone help me make my hard code to a code that uses threading.

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import pickle,time
import os
import imutils
import screeninfo
from screeninfo import get_monitors





curr_path = os.getcwd()
#########models##################################################
print("Loading face detection model")
proto_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'model', 'deploy.prototxt')
model_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'model', 'res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel')
face_detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt=proto_path, caffeModel=model_path)
print("Loading face recognition model")
recognition_model = os.path.join(curr_path, 'model', 'openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7')
face_recognizer = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch(model=recognition_model)
################pickles#########################################
recognizer = pickle.loads(open('recognizer.pickle', "rb").read())
le = pickle.loads(open('le.pickle', "rb").read())

print("Starting test video file")
#adjacents########################################################################
no_of_adjacent_prediction=0
no_face_detected=0  #to track the number of times the face is detected
prev_predicted_name=''   #to keep track of the previously predicted face(w.r.t frame)
count_frames = total_no_face_detected = 0
#camera#########################################################################
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
clr=(255,255,255)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2)

profile = None

####TRY_COUNTS###########
MAX_TRY=3
tries=0  #
######flags############
flag = True
flag_face_recognised=False   #to keep track if the user face is recognized
flag_face_not_recognised=False
#############FULLSCREEN###############
WINDOW_NAME = "Face-Rcognition and QRCODEQQQQQ"
screenid = 0
while True:
    cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    screen = screeninfo.get_monitors()[screenid]
    screen_width, screen_height = screen.width,screen.height

    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame_height, frame_width, _ = frame.shape

    scaleWidth = float(screen_width) / float(frame_width)
    scaleHeight = float(screen_height) / float(frame_height)

    if (flag):
        access = open("AccessCodes.txt")
        for i in decode(frame):
            decoded_data = i.data.decode("utf-8")  # converts bytes to string value
            print(decoded_data)

            # Drawing polygon on frame (tilts w.r.t orientation)
            pts = np.array([i.polygon], np.int32)

            pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
            cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 1)
            # print(pts)

            # Display text
            rect_pts = i.rect  # using rect point as origin for text as we don't want the text to tilt with the qrcode
            fontScale = 0.8
            thickness = 1
            # cv2.putText(frame,decoded_data,(rect_pts[0],rect_pts[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,fontScale,(255,0,0),thickness)
            # print(rect_pts)

            if decoded_data.lower() in access.read():  # Check private key
                flag = False
                tries = 0
                print("QRCODE is Valid.Proceed to FaceRecog")
                time_out_no_of_frames_after_qrcode = 0

            else:
                # print("INVALID QR CODE")
                print("Invalid QRCODE")
        if scaleHeight > scaleWidth:
            imgScale = scaleWidth

        else:
            imgScale = scaleHeight
            newX, newY = frame.shape[1] * imgScale, frame.shape[0] * imgScale
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (int(newX), int(newY)))
            cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame)
    else:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (int(newX), int(newY)))

        (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]

        image_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0), False, False)

        face_detector.setInput(image_blob)
        face_detections = face_detector.forward()

        for i in range(0, face_detections.shape[2]):
            confidence = face_detections[0, 0, i, 2]
            if confidence > 0.90:
                box = face_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
                (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
                face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
                (fH, fW) = face.shape[:2]
                face_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0/255, (96, 96), (0, 0, 0), True, False)

                face_recognizer.setInput(face_blob)
                vec = face_recognizer.forward()

                preds = recognizer.predict_proba(vec)[0]
                j = np.argmax(preds)
                proba = preds[j]
                name = le.classes_[j]

                text = "{}: {:.2f}".format(name, proba )
                y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, text, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 0, 255), 2)

                cv2.putText(frame, "Welcome home " + name.replace('_', ' ').title(), (160, 460), font, 0.8, clr,
                            thickness+3, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (255, 255, 255), 1)
                if name == decoded_data.lower():
                    print("Face is Recognised: "+str(no_of_adjacent_prediction))
                    no_of_adjacent_prediction += 1
                else:
                    print("Face not Recognised.")
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Face Not Recognised", (160, 460), font, 0.8, clr, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    flag_face_not_recognised = True
                    no_of_adjacent_prediction = 0
                if (no_of_adjacent_prediction > 10):  # no_of_adjacent_prediction is only updated when the confidence of classification is >80

                    flag_face_recognised = True
                    no_of_adjacent_prediction = 0
                    no_face_detected = 0
        cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame)
        if (flag_face_recognised):  # if face is recognized then open the door
            # arduino.write(bytes('o', 'utf-8'))  #Output the given byte string over the serial port.
            print("DOOR is OPEN")
            time.sleep(5)
            # speak("Closing door")
            # arduino.write(bytes('c', 'utf-8'))  #Output the given byte string over the serial port.
            print("DOOR is CLOSED")
            flag_face_recognised = False
            flag = True  # to start from qrcode

        if (flag_face_not_recognised):
            # speak("Face not recognised. The door will remain closed")
            time.sleep(2)
            flag_face_not_recognised = False
            tries += 1
            if (tries >= MAX_TRY):
                flag = True  # to start from qrcode
                tries = 0

        if (time_out_no_of_frames_after_qrcode >= 400):
            # speak("User authentication failed due to time out")
            flag = True  # to start from qrcode


    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> > > > > > FPS PC: 20 fps
> > > > > > FPS RASPBERRY PI : 9 fps

i tried various opencv codes and the result is still the same. I found a solution that threading increases the fps of opencv but i do not know how to apply this to my code due the fact that i am a noob python kid. a help would be nice. I want my fps in my raspberry ranging from 15-20 instead of 9 fps.

Comment: Threading will not help you one bit.  Facial recognition is a CPU-intensive task, and your processor is not powerful enough to do this operation any faster than 9 fps.  As a general rule, threading in Python is useless for CPU-bound tasks.  It's only a win for I/O-bound tasks.

Comment: that general rule only applies to pure python code. most packages (numpy, opencv) release the "global interpreter lock" for heavy operations, which allows multithreading to do what it's supposed to. -- all the DNN stuff in OpenCV is sure to use all the acceleration it can, which is threading, SIMD, OpenCL, ... it's already as parallel as it can get, so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Are you reading `AccessCodes.txt` after every frame? If so, you could surely read it once outside the main loop and make a set of access codes against which you can quickly test membership.

Comment: the ```AccessCodes.txt``` is inside the QRCode loop if i put the said .txt file outside the loop it can never be read after the whole process is completed. so the code breaks after that and the QRcode cant recognize the ```AccessCodes.txt``` anymore

Comment: [Increasing Raspberry Pi FPS with Python and OpenCV - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/28/increasing-raspberry-pi-fps-with-python-and-opencv/)